# Rellenar valores de un array con otra array no secuencial en php

Tags: php, array

estoy tratando de entender cómo poder resolver este problema.

Tengo un array con la siguiente información

```
 Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 5
            [auto] => volkswagen
            [grupo] => autos
            [color] => rojo
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 4
            [auto] => volvo
            [grupo] => autos
            [color] => negro
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [auto] => suzuki
            [grupo] => autos
            [color] => azul
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [id] => 3
            [auto] => ford
            [grupo] => autos
            [color] => morado
        )

)
```

y luego tengo otro array que contiene información adicional

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [auto] => volkswagen
            [color] => rojo
            [estado] => nuevo
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [auto] => suzuki
            [color] => azul
            [estado] => usado
        )

)
```

Como verán en este último array tengo 3 keys (2 keys pertenecientes al primero)
Me gustaría poder crear una tercera array como resultado que complete información de estado basado en las dos keys "auto" y "color" ejemplo:

**RESULTADO**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 5
            [auto] => volkswagen
            [grupo] => autos
            [color] => rojo
            [estado] => nuevo
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 4
            [auto] => volvo
            [grupo] => autos
            [color] => negro
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [auto] => suzuki
            [grupo] => autos
            [color] => azul
            [estado] => usado
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [id] => 3
            [auto] => ford
            [grupo] => autos
            [color] => morado
        )

)
```

He probado con array_replace_recursive, pero es secuencial vale decir me cambia el estado del auto volvo cuando quiero cambiar el estado del auto suzuki.

Me podrían dar alguna idea, sugerencia de cómo conseguirlo por favor

Gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No se si habrá una forma más eficiente, pero a falta de un indexado más óptimo no queda de otra que recorrer el segundo array por cada elemento del primero, preguntando si existe la combinación `'auto' and 'color'`.
Si existe la combinación, se agrega el item 'estado' que se encuentre en el elemento actual del segundo array:

```
$new_arr = array();
foreach($arr1 as $sub_arr1) {
    $sk1 = $sub_arr1['auto'];
    $sk2 = $sub_arr1['color'];
    $tmp = $sub_arr1;
    foreach($arr2 as $sub_arr2) {
        if(($sub_arr2['auto'] == $sk1) and ($sub_arr2['color'] == $sk2)) {
            $tmp['estado'] = $sub_arr2['estado'];
            break;
        }
    }
    $new_arr[] = $tmp;
}

print_r($new_arr); // ver resultado
```

[!] `$arr1` y `$arr2` son los arrays que suministraste.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, me sirvió bastante! y cómo sería un indexeado más óptimo si ambos array siempre serán diferentes, el primero siempre tendrás más data que el segundo